# Dyamic multidimensional array in Javascript that are related to each other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, parent

I'm still very new to array, my question is how do you links arrays one after another?

For example:
In the **season** array below, there are 4 keys/values, then in the **designer0** and **designer1** array, there are 3 keys/values pairs.

For **designer0** array, it's belong to **season[0]** and for **designer1** array, it's belong to **season[1]**, but how do I write it in such a way that there are parent and child related?

```
var season = new Array();
season[0] = "summer 2013";
season[1] = "winter 2014";
season[2] = "autumn 1998";
season[3] = "spring 2005";


var designer0 = new Array();
designer[0] = "Albbs";
designer[1] = "Alexander Wang";
designer[2] = "BCBG Max Azria";


var designer1 = new Array();
designer[0] = "William Howe";
designer[1] = "Bringingthewood";
designer[2] = "Kesha";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about javascript, you should remember: there are no native associative arrays in it. Since your `season` already contains data, the only way to maintain subordination is to create associative array, where season name will be a key and designers data - a value.

However, you can use array of objects to create desired data structure:

```
var seasons = [
    {
       "index"    : 0, 
       "name"     : 'summer 2013',
       "designers": ['Albbs', 'Alexander Wang']
    },
    {
       "index"    : 1, 
       "name"     : 'winter 2014',
       "designers": ['William Howe', 'Kesha']
    }
];
```

-see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NhB3r/) fiddle to check how to work with such data.

Answer (score 2):

You need a new type: "object", just like key & value.

```
var seasons = [{
    name: "summer 2013",
    designers: ["Albbs", "Alexander Wang", "BCBG Max Azria"]
}, {
    name: "winter 2014",
    designers: ["William Howe", "Bringingthewood", "Kesha"]
}];
```

object array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON:

```
  [
    {
    "season":"summer 2013",
    "designer1":"Albbs",
    "designer2":"William Howe"
    },
    {
    "season":"winter 2014",
    "designer1":"Alexander Wang",
    "designer2":"Bringingthewood"
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new array that links them and then refer to that array:

```
seasonal_designers =
[
0 = {designer0[0],designer0[1],designer0[2]}
1 = {designer1[0],designer1[1],designer1[2]}
]
```

Now get your stuff like this:

```
value=''
for(i in seasonal_designers[specify number])
value+=seasonal_designers[specify number][i] + ' (the designers id '+ i +')'
```